# Iterate Map with String and List<Object1> and replace to List<Object2>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use the Streaming concept to process the HashMap in Java.

Problem:

```
public class SourceClass{
    private String EmpId;
    private String EmpName;
}

public class ResultClass{
    private  String EmpId;
    private  String EmpAddress;
    private  String EmpMartialStatus;
    private  Integer EmpAge;
}
```

I have 2 class which will be used as List in the following method.

Now I should process this Map and using the SourceClass value I need to get the ResultClass value for which I have master data. So the response should be as follows.

```
 sourceClasseMap = { "doj1", 
                   <[EmpId1, EmpName1],                  
                    [EmpId1, EmpName1]> 
          }
```

My Result should be like

```
return ResultClassMap = { "doj1", 

   <[EmpId1, EmpAddress1, EmpMartialStatus1, EmpAge1],                                           
  [EmpId2, EmpAddress2, EmpMartialStatus2, EmpAge2]> 
}
```

Method looks like

```
public Map<String, List<ResultClass>> getStausesForDevices(Map<String, SourceClass[]> sourceClasseMap){

    Expecting to use Java 8 Stream concept.
    Expecting to use Java 8 Stream concept.
```

Comment: how can you fill `EmpAddress`, `EmpMartialStatus` and `EmpAge` for `ResultClass` from `SourceClass` ?

Comment: ResultClass = jedis.get(SourceClass.EmpId1 + SourceClass.EmpName1)

Comment: ok, what is `jedis.get` ? Can you please update the question

Comment: jedis is a Connection established with redis cache. If I pass the key(Source) will return the result as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

> ResultClass = jedis.get(SourceClass.EmpId1 + SourceClass.EmpName1)

And if you are not limited by java8, there is stream way with `flatMapping` method from java9:

```
public Map<String, List<ResultClass>> getStausesForDevices(Map<String, SourceClass[]> sourceClassMap) {

    return sourceClassMap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    flatMapping(entry -> Arrays.stream(entry.getValue()),
                            mapping(source -> jedis.get(source.getEmpId() + source.getEmpName()), toList()))));

}
```

**Update**

If you can't use java9, there is a solution without `flatMapping`:

```
return sourceClassMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> Arrays.stream(entry.getValue())
                .map(source -> jedis.get(source.getEmpId() + source.getEmpName()))
                .collect(toList())));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can use only java8 as my server configured with Java8. Can you please help with this?